# Editting bug on reviewer adding more info?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just sent in an edit onto [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049047/how-can-i-use-scriptmanager-more-than-one-function) question. However it got rejected, but it seems to me like the edit was still approved as it looks like my changes are in place. Did the user approve and add extra edits that counted solely as their own. Or was mine rejected then they only added their own after? Just wondering if my edit was wrong or if it was just a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [suggested edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9188279) says, your edit was rejected by the Community user because it conflicted with a subsequent edit.

Timeline of events like:

At 11:32:53 you suggested your edit.
At 11:34:58 (a little over two minutes later) a user with the edit privilege posted an edit.

The most obvious explanation is that the user did not see your suggested edit, and had already clicked into the "edit" page when you submitted your edit. When they submitted theirs, it over-wrote yours.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't know you could 'overwrite' edits as such